# How to integrate python into automake and exit the build process upon python syntax error

Tags: python, autoconf, automake

I have done my home work of looking for solutions.  I got a autoconf project with some simple python scripts.

In my configure.ac (only showing the relevant fragment):

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON([3.8])
```

I am trying to start using 3.x since 2.x is being deprecated next year (2020).

My Makefile.am:

```
python_PYTHON = uptocloud.py loadvariant.py
# I am not sure the following line is execute or the above one execute
# more likely the above one got executed
loadvariant : loadvariant.py
   ${PYTHON} -m py_compile $^ || exit 1
   @echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n${PYTHON} ${pythondir}/${@}.pyo \$$" > $@
   sed -i '2s,$$,*,' $@
   chmod +x $@
```

After configure --prefix $HOME, make, make install (only at the this step the python got compiled) I am getting the following error message:

```
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 uptocloud.py loadvariant.py load1variant.py '/home/myhome/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
<string>:2: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
Byte-compiling python modules...
uptocloud.pyloadvariant.py  File "/home/myhome/lib/python3.8/site-packages/loadvariant.py", line 57
    print "Connected to {} on {}!\n".format(pgdbname, hostname)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 Byte-compiling python modules (optimized versions) ...
 uptocloud.pyloadvariant.py
```

The error message is the typical python2 not compatible with python3 is not the matter of focus here. I was hoping to let the make process to stop here, but it continues all the way to the end and working on other build tasks. The ${PYTHON} -m py_compile FOO.py || exit 1 does not seems to be working here. This is a hand-written rule to overwrite the automatically generated implicit rules.

My question how do I let make stop here and ask me to fix syntax errors inside the python script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good answer but kind of 50% correct.  After I fix the above mention syntax error for the print. This time I tried the make install again, the build process did stopped.  Not sure why this happened. Here is an short version of the error message (removing redundant ones).

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myhome/coding/projname/scripts'
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m py_compile loadvariant.py || exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 144, in compile
    code = loader.source_to_code(source_bytes, dfile or file,
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "loadvariant.py", line 186
    print sqlstr
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(sqlstr)?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
# more lines of error removed here

NameError: name 'quiet' is not defined
Makefile:860: recipe for target 'loadvariant' failed
make[2]: *** [loadvariant] Error 1
```

Looks like the hand-written rule seems working. After fixing more syntax errors, sometime the make process skip some errors and sometimes it stops.  I am still missing something here.